# Why is the error in using Pyside6 and folium : Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file

Tags: javascript, python, gpu, folium, pyside6

I wrote a simple program using pyside6 and folium, and it reported an error after running it on a remote GPU server:
`Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file [1806129:7:0831/154330.501523:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(128)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer. js: crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.`

Why is there such an error？Below is part of my program：

```
class FoliumMapView(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # Create a Folium Map
        self.map = folium.Map(location=[108.1, 53], zoom_start=10) 

        folium.Marker([108.1, 53], tooltip='London').add_to(self.map)  # Add a marker for London

        # Save the Folium map as an HTML file
        self.map.save("folium_map.html")

        # Load the saved HTML map in the QWebEngineView
        self.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile("folium_map.html"))

class MapApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        central_widget = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        map_view = FoliumMapView()
        layout.addWidget(map_view)

        central_widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.setWindowTitle("Folium Map Viewer")

...

    def show_maps(self, checked):
        if self.w is None:
            self.w = MapApp()
            self.w.show()
        else:
            self.w.close()  # Close window.
            self.w = None  # Discard reference.


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = NetAPP()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

I've tried the following as per chatgpt's prompts but it didn't solve my problem：

1 Check Fontconfig Installation:

Ensure that the Fontconfig library is installed on your system. You can check if it's installed by running:
`fc-list` 
`sudo apt-get install fontconfig`
2 Set FONTCONFIG_PATH:
`export FONTCONFIG_PATH=/etc/fonts`

Comment: You said that you got an error, but it's not clear if the program actually works or not. If it works, you can probably ignore it.

Comment: It is not work. My QT window cannot open the Folium map, it is empty.